# Why does my iframe bug out when there's an animation on the parent's parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a block that appears every time an user clicks an element. Within this block, there's an embed youtube video - an iframe. So far so good, but when I try to go fullscreen with it, it just ends up a mess.

Here's the codepen /jsfiddle , it seems SO doesn't allow iframes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBvwVM

https://jsfiddle.net/h54kzqxc/

```css
@keyframes blockHelpFadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }
}

@keyframes blockHelpFadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0);
    }
}

.block-help-fade {
    animation: 0.75s cubic-bezier(.9,-0.42,.54,.73) 0s blockHelpFadeIn;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.block-help-fade-in {
    animation: 0.75s cubic-bezier(.9,-0.42,.54,.73) 0s blockHelpFadeOut;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.block-help-template {
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 24px;
    z-index: 99998;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    animation: 0.75s cubic-bezier(.9,-0.42,.54,.73) 0s blockHelpFadeIn;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 450px;
}

.block-help-top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 8;
    width: 100%;
}

.block-help-top .text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.block-help-title {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.block-help-description {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.block-help-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.block-help-video iframe {
    display: block;
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    animation: unset;
    animation-fill-mode: unset;
}
```

```html
  <div class="block-help-template ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="block-header-main-403a">
      <div class="block-help-top">
          <div class="text">
              <h3 class="block-help-title">Header Title</h3>
              <p class="block-help-description">Nice Description</p>
          </div>
          <div class="block-help-video">
              <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GuQBopNcve0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

As I said, all over the place (on codepen / jsfiddle, you can see it's bugged by the white lines on bottom + left):

[image: Messed up iframe]

But strangely enough, removing the

```
animation: 0.75s cubic-bezier(.9,-0.42,.54,.73) 0s blockHelpFadeIn;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Fixes the error.

I don't even know what to ask, what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

From the [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe
>   encountered during execution. The last keyframe depends on the value
>   of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count

Comment: That did it! But what would be another approach to solving this if I require `animation-fill-mode` on the parent?